# How to set different color within axis label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]
Hi everyone,
   I want to reproduce a picture like this in ggplot2, there is problem that I don't know how to set different color within the x axis label, the former part is 'red' and the latter part is 'black'. I would appreciate if you can give me some idea or suggestions!

best,
Wei

Comment: Hey there welcome to SO. Could you kindly make a reproducible example, otherwise your (very interesting) post will be soon closed. That means, give some sample data, and try to reduce your data to the minimum. And show what plot you have already tried...

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the `ggtext` package.

Will require a bit of fiddling to create the label expressions - you could automate this certainly in a fairly straight forward manner with `paste`.

```r
#devtools::install_github("wilkelab/ggtext")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(
    setosa = 
      "<span style='color:red'>GENE-</span><span style='color:black'>setosa</span>",
    virginica = 
      "<span style='color:red'>GENE-</span><span style='color:black'>virginica</span>",
    versicolor = 
      "<span style='color:red'>GENE-</span><span style='color:black'>versicolor</span>")
    ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown(angle = 90))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>